# Requires regex to compare last digit in string

Tags: javascript, regex

Requires regex to compare last digit in string.

```
// For example: 
const reg = RegExp("anythink...5") // expression to check that the last number is 5
reg.test("2fae71c8-a657-41b7-8d8c-3d4da10285fc") => true
reg.test("2fae71c8-fc5") => true
reg.test("2364872368745") => true
reg.test("87415B11-7143-4E5B-9B25-6117571DFEC8") => false
```

Please help me find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```js
/5(?=\D*$)/
/5(?!\D*\d)/
```

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
const reg = /5(?=\D*$)/
console.log(reg.test("2fae71c8-a657-41b7-8d8c-3d4da10285fc")) // => true
console.log(reg.test("2fae71c8-fc5")) //=> true
console.log(reg.test("2364872368745")) //=> true
console.log(reg.test("87415B11-7143-4E5B-9B25-6117571DFEC8"))// => false
```

The `5(?=\D*$)` regex matches

- `5` - a `5` digit char
- `(?=\D*$)` - a positive lookahead that requires zero or more non-digit chars till end of string
- `(?!\D*\d)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a digit after `5` and any zero or more non-digit chars.

Answer (score 0):

Use [regexr.com](https://www.regexr.com) to construct and check your Regular Expressions.
You can even add multiple tests to see if it works for you in a glance.

Answer (score 0):

You can match 5 optionally followed by any char except a digit or a newline using:

```
5[^\d\n]*$
```

You might also use `\D*` to match any char except a digit,  but note that it could also match a newline.

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/beAiNT/1).

```js
const reg = /5[^\d\n]*$/; // expression to check that the last number is 5
console.log(reg.test("2fae71c8-a657-41b7-8d8c-3d4da10285fc")); // => true
console.log(reg.test("2fae71c8-fc5")); // => true
console.log(reg.test("2364872368745")); // => true
console.log(reg.test("87415B11-7143-4E5B-9B25-6117571DFEC8")); // => false
```